# Show code similar to documentation of packages

Tags: packages, page-breaking, environments

I saw that several documentation packages use the environment to show macrocode long codes with page break, the example implementation of the package geometry. How do I do this?
I wanted to show a code along with page break.

Answer (score 3):

The [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides this by default if you don't allow the code to float. Here's a little example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{minted} \begin[linenos]{minted} bla bla bla \end{minted}`